# Neo4j cannot be started because the database files require upgrading and upgrades are disabled in the configuration

Tags: neo4j

Getting the error "**Neo4j cannot be started because the database files require upgrading and upgrades are disabled in the configuration. Please set '`dbms.allow_upgrade`' to '`true`' in your configuration file**" when I try to connect neo4j through its Java driver.

Despite that I have set the property `dbms.allow_upgrade` to `true` in the `neo4j.conf` file, nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, upgrade to the 3.3.1 neo4j Docker image! I tried the following but this didn't work either for 3.0:

```
 docker run \
  --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
  --env=NEO4J_dbms_allow_upgrade=true \
  --env=NEO4J_dbms_allow_format_migration=true \
  neo4j:3.0

===============================================================

fflintstone@OPTIPLEX790 MINGW64 /c/Users/fflintstone
$ docker run \
>     --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
>     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
>     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
>     --env=NEO4J_dbms_allow_upgrade=true \
>     --env=NEO4J_dbms_allow_format_migration=true \
>     neo4j:3.0
Starting Neo4j.
2017-12-26 06:47:03.172+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.0.12 ========
2017-12-26 06:47:03.228+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2017-12-26 06:47:04.204+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-12-26 06:47:05.140+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-12-26 06:47:05.560+0000 ERROR Neo4j cannot be started, because the database files require upgrading and upgrades ar
e disabled in configuration. Please set 'dbms.allow_format_migration' to 'true' in your configuration file and try again
.

fflintstone@OPTIPLEX790 MINGW64 /c/Users/fflintstone
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
neo4j               3.0                 39739226e15b        13 days ago         606MB

fflintstone@OPTIPLEX790 MINGW64 /c/Users/fflintstone
$ docker run     --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/l
ogs:/logs     neo4j:3.3.1
Unable to find image 'neo4j:3.3.1' locally
3.3.1: Pulling from library/neo4j
2fdfe1cd78c2: Pull complete
82630fd6e5ba: Pull complete
119d364c885d: Pull complete
46f8fad107ee: Pull complete
fe7f5c604f04: Pull complete
6fd4ca7c99ff: Pull complete
d242a75fec77: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:baeb76f0d4785817c2a3608796ff0104a8f87ed89fe3391ef467eb6f0a1fc40e
Status: Downloaded newer image for neo4j:3.3.1
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
  logs:         /logs
  plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
Starting Neo4j.
2017-12-26 06:51:42.867+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address
2017-12-26 06:51:42.872+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.raft_advertised_address
2017-12-26 06:51:42.872+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.raft_listen_address
2017-12-26 06:51:42.872+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.coordination
2017-12-26 06:51:42.872+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.transaction_advertised_address
2017-12-26 06:51:42.873+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.discovery_advertised_address
2017-12-26 06:51:42.873+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.data
2017-12-26 06:51:42.874+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address
2017-12-26 06:51:42.917+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.3.1 ========
2017-12-26 06:51:42.995+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-12-26 06:51:45.790+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-12-26 06:51:52.936+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-12-26 06:51:55.374+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

Comment: In my case, I had to replace `.` for `_` and `_` for `__` as follows: --env=NEO4J_dbms_allow__upgrade=true  --env=NEO4J_dbms_allow__format__migration=true

Comment: Here are the correct docker specific configurations https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/ref-settings/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the configuration file was not the one I thought.

According to [this documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/), it should have been under `<neo4j-home>/conf/neo4j.conf`

However, running `neo4j stop` and then `neo4j start` printed out a couple of key paths.

`Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /etc/neo4j
  logs:         /var/log/neo4j
  plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/run/neo4j`

So, editing the config found under `/etc/neo4j` worked.